# how can i delay form action?

Tags: javascript, php, html, payment-gateway

I created a form like this

```
<form id="donationpage" method="post" action='pgRedirect.php'>

    <div class="paytm_frm_field">    
        <label>Donation ID</label>
        <input id="ORDER_ID" tabindex="1" maxlength="20" size="20" name="ORDER_ID" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo  "DN" . rand(10000,99999999)?>">
    </div>
//and few more fields
<div class="sumbit_btn">
    <input value="Donate" type="submit" onclick="submitForm()">
</div>
</form>
```

my js look like this

```
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
var db = firebase.firestore();
// Custom Values
let ORDER_ID = document.getElementById('ORDER_ID').value;
let DONOR_NAME = document.getElementById('DONOR_NAME').value ;
let MOBILE_NUMBER = document.getElementById('MOBILE_NUMBER').value;
let EMAIL_ID = document.getElementById('EMAIL_ID').value;
let Amount = document.getElementById('TXN_AMOUNT').value;

document.getElementById('donationpage').addEventListener('submit',submitForm)
// Submit form
function submitForm(e){
e.preventDefault();

// Add data
db.collection("Donations").doc(ORDER_ID).set({
    Donor_Name: DONOR_NAME,
    Mobile_Number: MOBILE_NUMBER,
    Email_ID: EMAIL_ID,
    Donation_Amount: Amount,
    Payment_Status: "Pending",
    Payment_Date: "",
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", ORDER_ID);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
}
```

the submitForm function works if i dont put any value in a required field and submit the data get saved to my db which is done in submitform()

but if i completely fill the form in one go and submit it , it redirects to payment gateway without completing submitform()

what can i do here ?

e of preventDefault() is undefined :(

Comment: add the submitform() code

Comment: Forms can be submitted by user actions without clicking the submit button. Put the *submitForm* function on the form's submit listener, and [prevent the default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop submission until you're ready to submit it via script.

Comment: added submitfrom() code